# Apps suddently stopped sending notifications on my Nexus 7 (2013) running Lolypop 5.0.2

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

I have noticed that some apps (not all but a select few like Quizbattle and Wordfeud) have stopped sending notifications.

I have checked under App Info that notifications indeed is enabled, and other apps like Email and workout app are sending notifications fine!

I think it started doing this around when 5.0.1 was installed, but not sure. It persists after having installed 5.0.2

Nexus 7 (2013) is not rooted and install was done after tablet suggested updating, and all installs went without issues.

What could be causing this weirdness?

thanx for any suggestions in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion for a solution could be to first restart your phone and see if this helps (I have experienced many different bugs on the newest Lollipop that were fixed by simply restarting my phone).

If this does not work, try a reinstall of the app - if possible and you do not lose important data from that of course.

If the second option works, it could have been due to the 'optimizations' that Android performs on apps when updating to a newer system version (my best guess).

Comment: I have restarted the tablet several times, but reinstalling the apps (Wordfeud and Quizbattle) actually worked! Apparently some minor changes in 5.0.1 or 5.0.2 required **some** apps (but not all) to be re-installed for the notification to work! Thanx :)